# Reading USB Descriptors in a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application

Tags: c#, usb, uwp, hid, descriptor

I have a HIDDevice in a Universal Windows Platform application, that I would like to read the USB Descriptors of.

This is information like manufacturer, serial number etc.

The HidDevice does not seem to support this. I looks like the UsbDevice class does, but it does not allow to be created from a HID class device.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303351(v=vs.85).aspx

I tried to create a UsbDevice from a HidDevice id, but that fails.

Anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a 100% accurate answer, because I haven't tested it yet.

But a quick thought on this is to use platform interop.

So we can use the below API to get the HID serial number, see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539683(v=vs.85).aspx

Once you have it declared in your C# code, you can p-invoke it.

```
    [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool HidD_GetSerialNumberString(IntPtr HidDeviceObject, ref byte Buffer, Int32 BufferLength);
```

There's a nice open-source HidLibrary for your reference. https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are not allowed to use extern's in a UWP app :/

Comment: @soren.bendtsen, why not? I have verified it passes the windows store certification.